# Validating a form with JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
function validate(form) {
    var errors = 0;
    els = form.elements;
    for (var i=0; i<form.elements.length; i++) {
        if (!els[i].value && els[i].tagName != "select") {
            console.log(els[i]);
            els[i].style.border = "1px solid red";
            errors = 1;
        }
    }
    console.log("Finished for loop");
    var skuld_fast = document.getElementsByName("skuld_fast")[0];
    var skuld_other = document.getElementsByName("skuld_other")[0];
    if ((skuld_fast.value && !skuld_other.value) || (!skuld_fast.value && skuld_other.value)) {
        skuld_fast.style.border = "1px solid red";
        skuld_other.style.border = "1px solid red";
        errors = 1;
    }
    console.log("Finished if statement for skuld_fast and skuld_other");
    if (errors == 0) {
        form.submit();
    }
    else {
        alert("Eitthvað fór úrskeiðis.");
    }
}
```

The HTML:

```
<form>
    <input name="input1">
    <select name="skuld_other">
        (...)
    </select>
    <select name="skuld_fast">
        (...)
    </select>
    <input type="button" onClick="validate(this.form);">
</form>
```

`input1` works fine. `skuld_other` and `skuld_fast` do not, regardless of whether anything is selected or not. The `console.log` statements are both printed.

The statement I'm trying to make with this code is this: For each element (`input` or `select`) in the for loop of `form.elements`, if nothing has been written into the field, and the tag name of the element is not select, or it is the case that only either of `skuld_fast` and `skuld_other` have been chosen, then I set `errors = 1`.

I should note that for select I am using Select Picker: http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

Comment: A select field will always have an option chosen upon the page being loaded, so the value of `skuld_other` and `skuld_fast` will never be false unless set to "" by Javascript.

Comment: Ohh, I see. I'll have to test for whether the option is " " or something like that, then. But it still draws red borders around select elements even though I comment out the if statement that handles them. They still pass through the for loop for some reason.

Comment: If you commented out the if statement that handles them would that not mean that red borders get drawn no matter what? What lines exactly did you comment out?

Comment: I meant the standalone if statement which handles the "if only either of the two selects are chosen"

Comment: Did you comment out the if statement itself or the entire block (including the lines such as `skuld_fast.style.border = "1px solid red";`)?

Comment: I commented out the entire block.

Comment: Update: I removed the Selectpicker class, and it now seems to work if I select something frmo the lists. However, it still draws red if I leave the select elements empty...